# Ubuntu version for SIS Mirage 3 based laptop

Tags: 12.04, 13.04

What is the best  Ubuntu version for  [SIS Mirage 3](http://images.dailytech.com/nimage/2513_large_SiS_Roadmap_2007.png) vga based laptop. just to get 1280x800 resolution not 3D graphic. any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that the SIS Mirage support in Ubuntu 13.04 should be at least usable out of the box. Anyhow, 3D acceleration is probably not available, so I'd recommend to use a lightweight Ubuntu flavor that works without compositing. By default Xubuntu and Lubuntu don't use compositing, and on Kubuntu it can be disabled in the window manager settings.

[Source](http://useranswer.com/answer/where-do-i-get-a-sis-mirage-672-vga-driver/)

If you plan on using an LTS release (what I'd recommend, except if some hardware does not work - what might be the case for you), the following site recommends to use Xubuntu 12.04, but **not** Ubuntu 12.04, since in Ubuntu 12.04 the kernel and Xorg packages were updated meanwhile to versions that are incompatible with the drivers linked [there](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/sis).